# powershell script - send email once a week with info from event viewer

Tags: windows, powershell, events, logging, server

I was asked from my boss for a script that send him email once a week about computers in the company where windows antivirus have quarantined files (in the past week), and logs it somewhere. 
although i did find how to find those events:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName "Microsoft-Windows-Windows Defender/Operational"  | Where-Object {$_.id -eq 
1116}
```

I am now a bit lost and could really use and advice. how should i approach this now? anyone done something similar who can advice me?
Thanks so much in advance

Comment: take a look at `Get-Help *mail*`. then use the built in windows scheduler to run things on at intervals. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Get events and filter by id and TimeCreated (last 7 days)
# Also filter by TimeCreated and Message columns
$events = Get-WinEvent -LogName "Microsoft-Windows-Windows Defender/Operational" |
Where-Object {($_.id -eq 1116) -and ($_.TimeCreated -gt ((Get-Date).AddDays(-7)))} |
select TimeCreated, Message |
Format-List |
Out-String

# Message Data
$emailFrom = "noreply@domain.com"
$emailTo   = "foo@domain.com"
$subject   = "Computers where windows antivirus have quarantined files"

# Send message to smtpserver.domain.local (local network)
$smtpServer = "smtpserver.domain.local"
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $events)
```

Comment: Ty i will get back to this as soon as i get 15 rep and upvote the answer